# batch file else statement not working properly

Tags: batch-file

Good day,

I am still a bit new to batch files and coming from C++ and java some things are diffrent ...

I have a main batch which calls a sub batch, however when it returns, it goes into the else loop, i dont know why?

in the main batch the user selects and option:

```
set /p input=Enter:

if %input%==1 goto check
if %input%==2 goto check
if %input%==3 goto check
if %input%==4 goto delete
if %input%==A call %cd%\subbatch.bat %var1% %var2%\
if %input%==B call %cd%\subbatch2.bat %var1% %var2%
if %input%==C call %cd%\subbatch3.bat %var1% %var2% 
if {%input%}=={} (
    echo.
    echo Please enter a valid option
    echo.
    pause >nul
) else (
    echo %input%
    echo.
    echo Please enter a valid option
    echo.
    pause >nul
)
```

it goes to the subbatch, and when it returns it goes in the else loop,

I added the echo %input% in the else loop to see what was selected,

it shows input was A B or C depending on which i had selected,

however I wanted the else comand to only kick in if any other option other than 1-4 or A-C was selected,

would if be better to try:

```
if %input% GTR 4 (echo enter valid option)
```

but if I do that, what about the letters?

is there a way to compare letters? such as:

```
if %input% GTR "C" ( ....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this kind of menu, better options is to use `choice` command to only allow desired options.

BUT

Why is the execution entering the else part of the if. Because it is what it says. The check is `is input empty ?` and if the user has selected something, input is not empty so the if condition is false and the else executes.

If you want to keep the structure of `if else`, better do it this way

```
if "%input%=="a" (
    ....
) else if "%input%"=="b" (
    ....
) else if "%input%"=="1" (
    ....
) else (
    rem AND HERE falls the bad options
)
```